# Custom button with image background and multiple text views

Tags: android, button, view

Im my project I have a button which looks like this.

[image]

I have created a custom view with image resource as background and three text view, but I have a problem, on different screen sizes it looks different. Background stretches too much on big screens and text changes position.

What is the best way to do this this kind of button to make in adaptable for different screen sizes.

EDIT

This is xml for my custom view. The best way that I have found to do this is to use PercentLayout.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_button_main_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/custom_button_text_left_margin"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="12%"
    android:textSize="@dimen/custom_button_title_text_size"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_button_additional_left_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="70%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="20%"
    android:textSize="@dimen/custom_button_additional_text_size"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_button_additional_right_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="70%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="80%"
    android:textSize="@dimen/custom_button_additional_text_size"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    />
```

Comment: 9 patch image...

Comment: keep different density size image in different drawable folders(say, hdpi, xxhdpi), define dimensions on different density under values folder in dimens.xml(say, values-hdpi, values-xxhdpi)

Comment: Can you please post your xml code?

Answer (score 0):

if above is your custom view then you should use color and draw-able `xml` file with above shape and use dimensions for height and width.